# How Android Studio build different archs for native code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

In Android Studio 2 and above, you can use CMake to write native build script. And it automatically builds all the supported archs for you, which is great.

But not all library source code on the Internet are build by CMake. Most of them are still using the old `make` system.

I have a library that is using `make` build system. And I have managed to build in different `archs`. How do I tell the CMake build system in Android Studio which version of the library I want it to link to?

I check https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html, but there's no `ARCH` like variable.

Or maybe I can just drop the library in some place, and the CMake in Android Studio will be able to pick it up?

Comment: Did you see the section labeled 'Specify ABIs' in: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Comment: Looks promising. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the library compiled for each arch you could store them in app/src/main/jniLibs/{arch} for example: armeabi/armeabi-v7a/arm64-v8a
and then add the lines at the end of the the post to your apps build.gradle.

The productFlavours is used to configure the compilation variants, so this way you could link properly already compiled libraries.

```
android.ndk {
        moduleName = "your_library_jni"
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add("-I" + file("src/main/jni").absolutePath)
        }

android.productFlavors {
        create("armeabi") {
            ndk.with{
                abiFilters.add("armeabi")

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/"

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libyour_module.so")

            }
        }
        create("armv7-v7a") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/"

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libyour_module.so")

            }
        }
        create("arm64-v8a") {
            ndk.with{
                abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/"

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libyour_module.so")

            }
        }
    }
```